# Applying Newton-Raphson method for Bézier curve

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, cubics, newton-raphson

I would like to sort out why in the most browsers, part of algorithm doesn't correspond to Newton-Raphson method.

Ok, take a look at this opensource [code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-7600.1.25/platform/graphics/UnitBezier.h)
This code calculates y's coordinate (time easing function)

Part about I say, it is:

```
for (t2 = x, i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    x2 = sampleCurveX(t2) - x;
    if (fabs (x2) < epsilon)
        return t2;
    d2 = sampleCurveDerivativeX(t2);
    if (fabs(d2) < 1e-6)
        break;
    t2 = t2 - x2 / d2;
}
```

Again look at the follow string: `x2 = sampleCurveX(t2) - x;`
it will be used in the next formula as the `f(xn)`:

[image]

But there is the problem and my confusion. I don't understand for why we do need - `x2 = sampleCurveX(t2) - x;` I mean `-x` because it is not pure function of bezier and it doesn't correspond to upper formula of Newton-Raphson

P.S If you did not understand something, let me know, I'll give requirely extra information

Comment: Could you tell about the difference different browsers make? Does this algorithm compute different results?

Comment: I am not an specialist in browser's development but I can provide your some sources of different realizations.
There you go: 
https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/dom/smil/SMILKeySpline.cpp

https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/main/Source/WebCore/platform/graphics/UnitBezier.h

Comment: I do not see any difference, an attempt using Newton followed by bisection. Seems that is defined that way in the standard, else a bracketing method like the Illinois variant of regula falsi could replace both, or just the bisection branch.

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve $x=C(t)$ for $t$, $C$ standing for the curve component. Thus your function is $f(t)=C(t)-x$ with $f'(t)=C'(t)$, as $x$ is a constant in this context.

The initial value $t=x$ could be problematic, in general there is no direct relation between domain and range. I would use a secant root or some value obtained from a finer-grained reverse interpolation.

Reading the code, the Bezier curve is normalized in that module, both $x$ and $y$ component of the curve map the interval $[0,1]$ to itself. So taking $t=x$ as initial value is valid and corresponds to the mentioned secant root.

Comment: Past a lot of time after school, since I've completed it, I've forgotten basic of math. I am pretty sure that I need to learn math again :)
P.S Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it